# How can we show the printed file directly?

Tags: java, pdf-generation

I am using PD4ML jar  file to convert my HTML code into PDF file. And I am saving the file. Now the thing is I want to show that file directly after saved that file to user. Please suggest me.

Thanks,
Vara Kumar PJD

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

- Call Acrobat with the file. You don't have to know where it is installed, if you use cmd as a wrapper to start the acroread from java.
- Use your own PDF rendering library, like PDFOne.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a browser window with the full path of the PDF file as the URL - the browser should in turn kick off acroread to view the file. We use a barebones browser launcher by Dem Pilafian - here is the URL:

http://www.centerkey.com/java/browser/

Hope this helps.